# 12.04 isn't recognising my screen properly after an Nvidia failed driver update

Tags: nvidia, resolution, screen

I updated my Nvidia drivers via the **Additional Drivers** tab and the installation went ahead and installed then requested a reboot, after the reboot I lost the desktop and it instead booted to command line.  So in response to this I ran these 2 commands to repair it.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then reinstalled the drivers by running this.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

I regained my desktop environment after a reboot but since then my screen (Benq 27") is now shown under Displays as a Laptop and it will not detect the Benq, even though it does offer a full range of resolutions and aspect ratios.

Can someone please give me a push into the right direction please?

Comment: Unless zuberuber's answer has resolved the problem, would you please add the output of the following commands to your question: `sudo lshw -numeric -c video`, `lsmod`, and `xrandr -q` ? If the answer _has_ solved the problem would you please accept it so future visitors with a similar problem will know that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this steps:

1. Uninstall current driver
2. Remove `/etc/xorg.conf`
3. Install nvidia drivers through jockey or command line